# C: Incompatible pointer to integer conversion

Tags: c, datetime, time, integer

I have a struct with dates and time.

```
struct datetime{
int hour;
etc...}
```

When I try to assign the correct hour to my own struct-hour, I get an error.

```
struct tm tm_struct = *localtime(time(NULL));

dt->hour = tm_struct->tm_hour;
```

First I get an incompatible pointer conversion error on the first line, then I get an error about using `tm_struct.tm_hour` instead of `->`.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: `->` can only be used with pointers. Your `tm_struct` is not a pointer.

Comment: `dt->hour = tm_struct->tm_hour;` --> `dt->hour = tm_struct.tm_hour;`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no effort, I am pretty sure there are plenty of resources out there for that.

Comment: What about the first problem?

Comment: `localtime` expects a *pointer* to `time_t` as its argument. Instead you are passing `time_t` value itself. Did you try to read the man pages for these functions?

Comment: And regarding member access woes [this reference will probably help](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access).

Comment: @Rodbjartson: Um... No. Since it "expects a pointer", a naive attempt to fix this expression might look as `struct tm tm_struct = *localtime(&time(NULL))`. Note: `&`, not `*`. But this simply won't compile since you cannot apply `&` to a non-lvalue. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`localtime` expects a *pointer* to `time_t` as its argument. Instead you are passing `time_t` value itself, which is the root of your first problem. Typically because of this you will have to introduce an intermediate named `time_t` object to hold the result of `time`

```
time_t t = time(NULL);
struct tm tm_struct = *localtime(&t);
```

preventing you from using your original one-liner.

But by using *compound literals* you can still express it as a one-liner

```
struct tm tm_struct = *localtime(&(time_t) { time(NULL) });
```

if you so desire.

Comment: cheers, learned something new!